# Flutter: Why My Firestore Rules Are Not Working?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following firestore rules but they are not working.

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone with your Firestore database reference to view, edit,
    // and delete all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied until you Update
    // your rules
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2023,10, 30);
  }
    match /requests/{item} {
      allow update,write,create: if request.resource.data.commision > 0;
    }
    
     match /businesses/{business} {
      // Allow the user to delete cities if their user document has the
      // 'admin' field set to 'true'
      allow delete: if  get(/databases/$(database)/documents/requests/{requestId}).data.business_received != business
      && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/requests/{requestId}).data.business_send != business  
    }     
    
  }
}
```

In my flutter app i can still add a new request model with negative commision value and also delete a business model even if there are requests to that business.

i was expecting for the rules to throw me an error so i can display it to the user, but it updates the database ignoring both of the rules.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#overlapping_match_statements) "In the case where multiple allow expressions match a request, the access is allowed if any of the conditions is true"

With

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2023,10, 30);
}
```

you allow all reads and writes **for all documents in the database** (until 30 Oct 2023) so your other rules are not taking into account.

Deleting it should solve your problem.

Comment: Hey @dev_flutter, did my answer solved your problem?